# Importing Windows registry to a file structure

Tags: c#, registry, filenames, file-structure

I need help from someone someone smarter than I am to solve this puzzle.

I have a Registry branch that I want to convert into a file structure. Users make changes in the file structure, mostly because its easier for lusers to manipulate files. Then I can write those changes back to the registry.  (I realize the risk here, please don't tell me that doing this is "bad", I know. This code is for a personal project and not going into any production models!)

So far my code works great:

[image: Good Registry Values]
This translates great to:
[image: Good Explorer Values]

However, since the registry is NOT a file structure, we can have "bad" keys such as:

[image: Bad Key]

This makes a file named Banana, in directory ...\Branch2\SubBranch1\Apple.  Obviously.  I thought about replacing the '\' with something, but what?

There is also an issue with ending a key or value with a '.'  The file will not have the period.

Does anyone have a solution (or suggestion) to obtain the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

A simple character substitution map should accomodate you just fine.

backslash could be the arabic question mark: ؟
and slash could be the greek capital letter omega with dasia and prosgegrammeni: ᾩ

of course you would have to pick substitutions that were legal filesystem characters as well as characters that had a near zero chance of existing in a real registry key.  But the unicode "alphabet" is quite large.  Shouldnt be too much of a problem.  The trailing period could be handled the same way.

`charmap.exe` is your friend

Answer (score 0):

there is a couple of character that you need to handle /:?"<>|
if the key value contain one of this character then you can't name your file with the same name as a key value
i suggest you to use XML structure its very easy to maintain and manipulate